# In Linekdin.com. the document.querySelectorAll (".className") does not work

Tags: javascript, html, linkedin-api

```
<h3 class="Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold">Director of Entrepreneurship Programs</h3>
```

This is the Linkedin html code and I'm trying to select, using ...

```
<i>let x = document.querySelectorAll (".Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold")</i>,
```

but I always get an error like

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': >'.Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold' is not a valid selector.

However, I am able to select other elements on the page, but not the CV part.

Can someone explain me why this happens and how to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove % in the class name and try .

Comment: @Suresh — It is a third party site. The OP does not have control over the class names used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Identifiers may not contain unescaped per cent characters. You need to escape it.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".Sans-17px-black-85\\%-semibold")
```

Note that the per cent sign needs escaping for the selector syntax and then the escape character needs escaping for the JS string literal syntax.

Alternatively, you could avoid using selector syntax:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold")
```

Comment: Thanks. This option worked document.getElementsByClassName("Sans-17px-black-85%-semibold"). The other one gave me Nodelist with length of 0.